# Where can I find alternative folder icons?

Tags: nautilus, icons

I want to find alternative icons for nautilus folder.

I don't want to find application or something else icons But Icons for **Folders only** (In other words **Alternative Nautilus folder/directory icons**.)

Where it is located (if provided)? or I have to download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Open Nautilus**

In Nautilus file browser, right click a folder icon, select Properties.

2) **Edit Icon Settings**

Under the Basic tab, click the icon image to open up the “Select Custom Icon” window.

3) **Search for Icon Image**

In the Location field, type `/usr/share/icons`, press Enter. (You can hide or unhide the Location field by clicking the Edit button on the top-left of the window.)

Watch this subfolder as well:
`/usr/share/icons/Humanity/emblems/48/`

4) **Choose Icon Image**

Browse and select an icon you want.

5) **Save Changes**

Click the Open button on the bottom-right of the window to confirm.

6) **Close Properties window**

Click the close button to close the properties window and finalize the new settings.

Also have a look at applications icons
`/usr/share/app-install/icons/`

You can alternatively download and set what you like, for example from here:

http://www.iconarchive.com/tag/ubuntu-folder

---

Here are some example icons can be downloaded:

[image][image][image][image][image]